# Need Help / How to open only one trade per session?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm looking for a solution to my strategy. I want to open only one strategy.entry long and one strategy.entry short per session. The timeframe of my session looks like this.

```
sessionTime = input.session("0015-2245", title="Session time")
sessionZone = input.string("GMT+1", title="Session time zone")

inSession    = InSession(sessionTime, sessionZone) and timeframe.isintraday
sessionStart = inSession and not inSession[1]
SessionEnd = inSession[1] and not inSession
```

So there shouldn't be more than two new entries (1*long Max/ 1*Short Max) per day. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of achieving this.

One example would be using a `var` variable to check whether you have entered before in the same session. You should then reset this when it is a new session.

```
var entered_before = false
entered_before := sessionStart ? false : entered_before  // If it is a new session, reset the variable. Keep its value otherwise

if (entry_condition and not entered_before)
    strategy.entry()
    entered_before := true
```

Of course, you need two of these variables (one for short and one for long).

Another idea would be to compare `strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index` of the last trade with `ta.barssince(sessionStart)`. If `strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index` is less than `ta.barssince(sessionStart)`, you would know that that entry took place in the current session.